# Remove a specific element from an Arraylist in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an Arraylist with (String-)Arrays in it. Now I want to be able to delete a specific element from the Arraylist.

Here is an example arraylist:

```
0:  [Name, , , ]
1:  [Telefon, \(\d+\) \d+, DAFAE8, FF6262]
2:  [E-Mail, ^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:(\.|_)[A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^`{|}~-]+)*@(?!([a-zA-Z0-9]*\.[a-zA-Z0-9]*\.[a-zA-Z0-9]*\.))(?:[A-Za-z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9])?\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?$, DAFAE8, FF6262]
3:  [Company, , , ]
4:  [Test, , , ]
5:  [Test2, , , ]
6:  [Test3, , , ]
```

Now I want to delete the 5th element (the array which includes Test2). How do I accomplish that?

I already tried the following things:

```
public static List<String[]> removeSpecificElements(List<String[]> list, int i){
    list.remove(new Integer(i));
    return list;
}
```

This one doesn't throw any kind of Exception, but doesn't work either.

```
public static List<String[]> removeSpecificElements(List<String[]> list, int i){
    list.remove(i);
    return list;
}
```

This one throws ArrayIndexOutOfBounds.

```
public static List<String[]> removeSpecificElements(List<String[]> list, int i){
    Iterator<String[]> itr = list.iterator();
    itr.next();
    for (int x = 0; x < i; x++){
        itr.next();
        System.out.println(itr);
    }
    itr.remove();
    return list;
}
```

And this one always removes the first element.

Could you please help me?

Comment: There are numerous questions about how to delete elements from a list on this site. Did you bother searching for them first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Now I want to delete the 5th element (the array which includes Test2). How do I accomplish that?

You need to use

```
list.remove(i); // where i = 5 - 1, as the first element is 0.
```

if you do

```
list.remove(new Integer(i));
```

it will look for the object you just created, which doesn't exist in the list, so as you say it does nothing.

In short, don't confuse `int` for `Integer` as these are different types.

Ideally, the API would have a different method like `removeAt(int)` to remove this potential source of confusion, but it's too late to change it now.

---

When would this work?  Consider the following.

```
List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>();
ints.add(4);

List<MyType> list = (List) ints; // it works but don't do this.
boolean wasRemoved = list.remove(new Integer(4)); // true!!
```

Comment: I would maybe say that `new Integer(i)` *can't* exist in the list (rather than simply doesn't), because of generics.

Comment: @AndyTurner actually it could exist if you had used generics incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks, this made me realize my mistake. (which basically was that I first select an visual element, remove it and then try to remove the data behind the element with the now non-existant selection...)

Comment: @WorkHardDieSoon unfortunately its a reasonably common mistake to make.

Answer (score 3):

`java.util.List#remove(int)` should work, just don't forget that lists are zero indexed, i.e. 5th element is removed calling `list.remove(4)`